# Consistently change format of DATE columns to CHAR

Tags: sql, r, r-dbi, roracle

Within R I am receiving tables from an Oracle database. However, unfortunately something is going wrong in the conversion within ROracle: dates are converted to POSIXct but for some strange reason same dates can differ by one hour (see my other post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44265617/dbgetquery-returns-date-that-differs-by-an-hour)). In the end I need the dates in R as a string (for consistency reasons with already existing code) in the format "dd/mm/yyyy". So for example, I will change the query

```
SELECT PK_CASHFLOW_DATE FROM MYTABLE
```

to

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(PK_CASHFLOW_DATE, 'mm/dd/yyyy') FROM MYTABLE
```

However, in the R code the query is dynamically build up and upfront I do not know which columns of the table are `DATE` columns. How can I still modify a query consistently such that it will always change the `DATE` columns into a char as described above.

Thanks!

Comment: Off by one-hour problems are usually a sign of daylight savings time problems.

Comment: ....or multiple locations saving to the same database from different time zones with a Z adjustment, each saving their own time, instead of an absolute time agreed upon in advance.